# Is it possible to prevent auto delete message after read in Msmq

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, msmq

IDE: VS 2010, Winforms:

I am having a simple msmq send/receive application, I have a requirement in which I will read the message and based on message I will call other function if that function is not ready then I want message to be in queue.

My Msmq Send receive code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MSMQ Send :
        if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\MyQ"))
        {
            myQ = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\MyQ");
        }
        else
        {
            myQ = MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\MyQ");
        }

        string xmlText = getxmlString();

        System.Messaging.Message msg = new System.Messaging.Message();

        msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter();
        msg.Body = xmlText;
        msg.Label = "MyXmlMessage";
        msg.Priority = MessagePriority.Normal;
        myQ.Send(msg);

    }  


 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MSMQ Receive
        myQ = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\MyQ");

        System.Messaging.Message myMsg = myQ.Receive();
        myMsg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
        bool IsValidated  = Validate(myMsg.Body.ToString());
    }  

    internal void Validate(string message)
    {
        //some logic  
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see in receive code, I am receiving the message back and validating the message, Here I want that message to be deleted from queue only if the IsValidated is true,

Basically I want to prevent the auto delete message future to false and want to delete that message in queue if it is validated.

can you tell me what modification shall i make to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/829zyck7(v=vs.110).aspx)?

**MessageQueue.Peek Method**

Returns without removing (peeks) the first message in the queue referenced by this MessageQueue. The Peek method is synchronous, so it blocks the current thread until a message becomes available.

Comment: I don't knew about that, let me try

Comment: Okay so peek method will be useful, but can you tell me after peek if message is validated how to delete that message from queue manually for eg. thatMessage.delete()

Comment: just call `Receive()` as per normal

Comment: So suppose I peeked message A and it is validated in 2 secs, in between queue received higher priority message B, and If I do myQ.receive(), so this can create a problem, like I peeked message A but message B is deleted, How will you handle this?

Comment: that defeats the purpose of Queue (First in first out). You'll have to process Message A before even `Peek` or `Receive` Message B

Comment: Can you suggest a better way, In that I can peek that message and if validated I delete that message, eg. A.delete()

Comment: sorry I think I've misread your comment. If you `Peek` Message A, meanwhile Message B arrives, calling `Receive` will only remove Message A, and Message B becomes the first message in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
messageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(
  new Type[] { typeof(System.Xml.XmlElement) });
MessageEnumerator iter = messageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
iter.Reset();
while (iter.MoveNext(new TimeSpan(1000)))
{
    System.Messaging.Message msg = iter.Current;

    msg.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
    var reader = new StreamReader(msg.BodyStream);

    var msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.